# set dropdown option value based another dropdown onchange function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to make multiple dropdown option value to be the same as dropdown value with `id=monday` on change function.

```
  monday
    <select id="monday">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    </select>

    tuesday
    <select id="tuesday">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    </select>

    wednesday
    <select id="wednesday">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    </select>
```

JS

```
$("#monday").change(function() {
  $("#tuesday").value = $("#monday").value;
  $("#wednesday").value = $("#monday").value;
});
```

i saw the example with assign dropdown name with array like `name="dropdown[]"`, but i want to keep the id like i wrote. Thanks in advance

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes, i want to change tuesday and wednesday based on value on monday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing would happen when you have updated `value` property, which only works with DOM element. So use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method for jQuery object, although you can combine selectors into one by separating them using a comma.

```
$("#monday").change(function() {
  $("#tuesday,#wednesday").val(this.value);
});
```

```js
$("#monday").change(function() {
  $("#tuesday,#wednesday").val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
monday
<select id="monday">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
  <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
  <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
  <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
  <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
</select>

tuesday
<select id="tuesday">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
  <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
  <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
  <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
  <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
</select>

wednesday
<select id="wednesday">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
  <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
  <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
  <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
  <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @highcal : you ar missing jQuery library in fiddle

Comment: @highcal : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to sync any other to monday

```js
$(function() {
  $("#monday").on("change", function() { // or .sel for all
    $(".sel").not(this).val(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
monday
<select class="sel" id="monday">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
  <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
  <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
  <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
  <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>tuesday
<select class="sel" id="tuesday">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
  <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
  <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
  <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
  <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>wednesday
<select class="sel" id="wednesday">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
  <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
  <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
  <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
  <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
</select>
```